# change fck editor content dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, editor, fckeditor

i want to change **fck editor** content **dynamically**

When i change select box option`(on change)` the value of the fck editor should change

Any possible in php or javascript (fck editor configuration )

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found answer myself,and happy to share here..

call the `chagefck(this)` javascript function form your select box

```
<select name="select" onchange="javascript:chagefck(this);">
    <option value="op">opt1</option>
    <option value="op">opt2</option>
    </select>
```

textarea will be replaced as fck editor

```
<textarea name="product_long_tescription" id="product_long_tescription"   class="fillbymaster" >init value</textarea>
```

and bellow javascript doing the hole job here !

```
<script type="text/javascript">

// fck initializing 
window.onload = function()
{
var oFCKeditor = new FCKeditor( 'product_long_tescription' ) ;
oFCKeditor.BasePath = "../fckeditor/" ;
oFCKeditor.Height = "300" ; 
oFCKeditor.Width = "900";
oFCKeditor.ReplaceTextarea() ;

}

//dynamically 
function chagefck(value)
{
        var Editor1 = FCKeditorAPI.GetInstance('product_long_tescription');
        Editor1.SetHTML(value);

    return false;   
}
</script>
```

the `SetHTML` function will place your value in fck editor

Thanks